# Should I remove a tag if the question isn't specifically about the tag's topic?

Tags: discussion, tags, edits

For example, if I encountered the following question:

> In C++ I can increment `int a` like so: `a++`. How is this done in Java?

If this question is tagged with `C++`, should I remove the `C++` tag?

To ask this generally, is using a topic as a reference for a question grounds for tagging it with that topic?

My own initial reaction is to remove the tag, as people looking to answer `C++` questions will be unable to help with this question.

Answer (score 6):

In an example as simple as the one you posted, it is probably safe to remove [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b); most (if not all) programming languages include a way to increment a value, so the concept is widely known.

However, some questions require specialized domain knowledge in *both* languages. If a question is about porting a C++-specific feature to Java, and only someone versed in both C++ and Java could provide a relevant answer, the question should include both tags.

For example, if someone requested an equivalent of PHP's `die()` in Ruby, the answerer would need a working understanding of the functionality provided by `die()` to provide the answer (`abort()`).

Comment: I'm not sure I completely agree here.  Code conversion, to me, is only appropriate if it's written in such a way that it could (technically) be answered without knowing the other language, only including the other languages' code as clarification.  From a tag-searcher/subscriber point of view, in your example, a [tag:php] subscriber wouldn't want to read that question, unless they also read [tag:ruby], would they?

Comment: @Joe Code conversion (like any translation) _requires_ knowledge in both languages except in the very simplest cases. As to your second question about whether someone with knowledge of the first domain would want to see such questions, the example I provided [really happened](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6144112/rails-equivalent-to-php-die/). I was able to provide an answer because I knew PHP. In fact, I new very little Ruby at the time, but was able to successfully Google the answer specifically because I knew what `die()` did, and was quite happy to answer the question.

Comment: From other meta threads (which I can't recollect at the moment), my understanding was that complex code conversion (ie, more than the simplest cases) is off-topic for SO if it can't be phrased in a manner that does not require knowledge of the original code.  IE, the questions like I saw yesterday - "I have this excel code, I want to write it in SAS".  Phrase it as "I have a dataset I want to merge to blah blah blah, currently am doing this in excel, how to in SAS" and it's ok, because a non-excel-using SAS programmer could answer it.

Comment: Sure, but the matter of whether something is off-topic is a separate discussion. Briefly though, some such questions are on-topic if they are asked correctly: _I tried converting C++'s `foo()` to Java's `bar()` but encountered error `baz`. Why?_

Answer (score 5):

Yes, tags should be related to the question's ultimate goal - the answer.  The c++ information in that question is useful for asking the question (for making clear what you're looking for in the answer), but is not relevant to the answer itself; having knowledge in c++ and not java is not helpful to answering the question.

Answer (score 0):

If a question is not specific to the language tagged you should ask the OP to change the tag(s). That process gets around the community decision to not change the tags in this case.

For other topic tags it is more within the community standards to "correct" them directly.

Also, for more complex questions, but otherwise like your example, you want it seen by people fluent in both languages, so it makes sense to keep both languages' tags.